# Suppose $f$ satisfies $f '' - f = 0$ and $f (0) = f '(0) = 0.$ Prove that $f$ is the null function of the following mode:

Tags: calculus

a) Show that $f^2 - (f')^2 = 0$

I tried to solve by doing $f=\pm f'$ not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Not sure if the title and body are in good agreement

Comment: This question has appeared in one of my calculus exams

Comment: Compute the derivative of $f^2 -  f'^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $g=f^2-(f')^2$. One has

$$g'(x)=2f(x)f'(x)-2f''(x)f'(x)=2f'(x)\left(f(x)-f''(x)\right)=0$$

So $g$ is constant and by assumption $g(0)=0$ so $f^2-(f')^2=0$

This means $f'(x)=f(x)$ or $f'(x)=-f(x)$.

Solving these two ODE one gets $f(x)=f(0)e^x=0$ or $f(x)=f(0)e^{-x}=0$

Answer (score 0):

$(f-f')(f+f')=0$

$\implies f'=f $ or $f'=-f$.

Try solving the two IVP's:

$1$. $f'(x)-f(x)=0$ with $f(0)=f'(0)=0$.

$2$. $f'(x)+f(x)=0$ with $f(0)=f'(0)=0$.

Both have a unique solution which $f(x)=0$.